# angular2 nested component templateUrl will not be find

Tags: angular, nested, components

i would like use nested component.
This fine tutorial shows, how could i do that:

```
https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/building-nested-components-in-angular-2/
```

My problem is, that my template for the nested component will not be found:
I have try

```
template: '<h2>HALLO</h2>'
```

But i would like use extern file: task.component.html like this:

```
 template: 'file.component.html'
```

Output is, that simply

> task.component.html

will be displayed
and when i try:

```
templateUrl: 'file.component.html'
```

i get error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load task.component.html

Here is my code:

ChildComponent:

```
@Component({

    selector: 'edit-task',
    templateUrl: 'file.component.html'

})
export class FileFormat{}
```

ParentComponent:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.template.html',
    directives: [FileFormat]
})
export class FileFormat{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id
    selector: 'edit-task',
    templateUrl: 'file.component.html'

})
export class FileFormat{}
```

actually the problem is angular is not getting the path properly , to use it relative path use `moduleID`

or either give the full path in telplateUrl from the root